# How to Display Two Levels of Custom Post Type in Alpha Order?

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, custom-post-type, hierarchy

I need to display two levels of a custom post type posts in alpha order -- while maintaining the parent/child hierarchy. Here's my existing code:

```
<select class="form-select filter-select" name="..." aria-label="...">
<?php $post_type = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
) );
if ( $post_type ) {
    foreach ( $post_type as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <option value=".<?php print $post->post_name; ?>"><?php if ( $post->post_parent) { ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- <?php } ?><?php the_title(); ?></option>
        <?php
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
</select>
```

This will display the posts in alpha order -- but the child posts aren't properly displaying under their parent post. How can I address this?

UPDATE: This is for a standard Wordpress site. Not WooCommerce.

Thank you for your help.